# Lagrange's undetermined multiplier

Tags: real-analysis

I have been struggling with this problem for a while, please help me out..
Use Lagrange's undetermined multiplier to find the points on $\frac {x^2} 4+ \frac {y^2} 9=1$ which are at maximum and minimum distances from the line $3x+y=9$

Comment: What's throwing you off? It seems like a pretty standard problem in this topic.

Comment: $\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ is the closest and $\left(-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)$ the farthest. Without Lagrange.